# java.util.Map in output of REST Service using jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using apache jersey 2.2 and I have the following rest service

```
@GET
@Path("load3")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public LocalizationContainer load3() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");

    return new SampleContainer(map);

}


@XmlRootElement
```

public class SampleContainer{

```
public SampleContainer(){
}

public SampleContainer(Map<String,String> map){
    this.map = map;
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = MapAdapter.class)
private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

}

and MapAdapter is defined as follows:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, String>> {

public static class AdaptedMap {
    @XmlVariableNode("key")
    List<AdaptedEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AdaptedEntry>();
}

public static class AdaptedEntry {
    @XmlTransient
    public String key;
    @XmlValue
    public String value;
}

@Override
public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, String> map) throws Exception {
    AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry = new AdaptedEntry();
        adaptedEntry.key = entry.getKey();
        adaptedEntry.value = entry.getValue();
        adaptedMap.entries.add(adaptedEntry);
    }
    return adaptedMap;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
    List<AdaptedEntry> entries = adaptedMap.entries;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(entries.size());
    for (AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : entries) {
        map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

the output of the rest service is

```
{"map":{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"}}
```

but I do not want the root element. My desidered output is the following:

```
{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"}
```

What can I do to accomplish this goal ?
Is it possible ?

many thanks

Comment: What deserializer are you using? I suggest you use Jackson. Jackson has mo problem with `Map`s and if you _really_ want to keep the wrapper class (don't really see why) you can can put `@JsonAnyGetter` on the `getMap` and it will not serialize the `map` property, but instead add the map keys as properties on `SampleContainer`

Comment: @peeskillet thanks. Do you mean I can return the Map itself without using a wrapper class ? Is it possible ? If I return the java.util.Map I got an error from jersey.

Comment: That's why I asked what serializer you are using. If you're using MOXy, it's a no go. If you use Jackson, it should work fine

Comment: I am using MOXy right now. Do you mean that using Jackson I can return java.util.Map ? Will it be serialized correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using @XmlPath annotation.

In this way:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = MapAdapter.class)
@XmlPath(".")
private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

the map is serialized in the json itself without "map" reference.